# Retrieving field stored in a class as byte array

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm, jvm-bytecode

I'm experimenting with the ASM library.

I have a class stored as a `byte[]`, i.e beginning with CAFEBABE, with a constant pool, etc.

I want to load this class and extract a field in a way as convenient as possible, as this procedure would be added to a method with ASM.

Is there a simple way to load a byte array as a class without messing with custom classloaders and the like?

Comment: As far as I know, ASM doesn’t provide you an alternative API. But what’s wrong with creating a subclass of `ClassLoader` (doesn’t need any additional members) and invoking `defineClass` on it?

Comment: Is it not possible to use the system class loader?

Comment: The method `defineClass` is `protected`. You can use Reflection and access override to invoke the method on the system class loader, but that’s not simpler than creating a subclass of `ClassLoader` with no additional members.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Misread the question. You want to literally load the class?

```
static class BLoader extends ClassLoader {
    public BLoader(ClassLoader parent) {
        super(parent);
    }

    public Class<?> get(String name, byte[] bytes) {
        return defineClass(name, bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    }
}
```

Used by:

```
Class<?> clazz = new BLoader(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()).get("ClassName", cw.toByteArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

We use a custom ClassLoader because we need apublic defineClass() method. So all you have to do is literally this.

```
public class GenericClassLoader extends ClassLoader {

    public Class<?> defineClass(String name, byte[] b) {
        return defineClass(name, b, 0, b.length);
    }

}
```

And to load the class.

```
GenericClassLoader classLoader = new GenericClassLoader();
Class<?> clazz = cl.defineClass("class name", classWriter.toByteArray());
```

If you have a ClassNode and want to generate the class depending on the class name you can use classNode.name, like this.

```
Class<?> clazz = classLoader.defineClass(cn.name, classWriter.toByteArray());
```